# How to check if a string has consecutive whitespace 3

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a textbox and I want to invalidate two or more consecutive white-spaces in the field using *javascript*.

Answer (score 3):

This regular expression looks for 3 or more white spaces chars.

```
/\s{3,}/
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DMZRB/1)